# SCons: prevent $TEXT expansion in construction variable

Tags: scons

When I call a builder `Program(Target, Source, CXXFLAGS=CompileFlags)` the value of CompileFlags string contains `-Wl,-rpath,lib:$ORIGIN/../lib` causing $ORIGIN to be expanded to empty string, while it should be preserved as is.

I tried escaping the dollar sign, adding single quotes inside, nothing helps.

`env['RPATH'] = Literal('lib:$ORIGIN/../lib')`

also does not work: it produces

`g++ -o main -Wl,-rpath=lib:/../lib`

in command line even though the man page says *"the paths added to RPATH are not transformed by scons in any way"* so it supposed to work even without Literal(), I guess.

So how can I add a compiler flag containing $TEXT without SCons trying to expand it as a variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use double dollars, like this:

```
env['RPATH'] = Literal('lib:$$ORIGIN/../lib')
```

Comment: I tried this lots of different ways and I just couldn't get it to work. Searching the entire Scons manual, there is NO place where it says to use double dollars; the only mechanism they provide is Literal().

Answer (score 5):

I found this can solve the expansion problem

```
    Env['ORIGIN'] = Literal('$ORIGIN')
    Env['RPATH'] = Literal('\'$ORIGIN/../lib:lib\'')
```

Please, let me know if you aware of more proper/elegant solution without.

Answer (score 1):

This answer expand's jackhab's answer by showing how to do a literal dollar sign in a different context, and then explaining how the "black magic" works. I want to share what I learned in an hour of trial and error.

My problem was how to send "$p" to Inno Setup as part of a very cryptic command line to automate having Inno Setup sign the created setup program (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73045226/831520 if you are interested in that). The only way I could get it to work was by using jackhab's double env/Literal trick. Here's my scons code:

```
env['DOLLARP'] = env.Literal('$p')
args = '"/sStandard=' + getSignTool()
args += ' sign /a /f C:\Confidential\MyCompanysCertificate.p12 /p ' + password
args += ' /tr http://timestamp.sectigo.com/?td=sha256 /td sha256 /fd SHA256 $DOLLARP"'
args += ' "' + str(source[0]) + '"'
env['MYARGS'] = env.Literal(args)
env.Execute('iscc $MYARGS')
```

Now the question is, how does this actually work, and why are $DOLLARP and $MYARGS necessary?

A lot of it boils down to how Literal() works. The scons documentation is very brief: "The specified string will be preserved as-is and not have construction variables expanded." So one would think you could do things like this:

```
MyString = "iscc " + env.Literal("$p")
env.Execute(env.Literal("iscc $p"))
```

But neither of these work! env.Literal() apparently doesn't create a normal string, and the scons documentation doesn't give any example. The only context, then, seems to be the context that jackhab and mcinek provide, which is an assignment to an environment variable.

Another issue is that the string substitution isn't done immediately (i.e., python doesn't do it); it's only done when scons "processes" the string in some way. env.Literal() DOES preserve a dollar sign, but if you then use the environment variable somewhere else, scons "processes" the string a second time and does its normal substitution!

So let's walk through it:

```
env['DOLLARP'] = env.Literal('$p')
```

This assigns "$p" to $DOLLARP, but we need env.Literal() so scons doesn't think $p is an environment variable lookup.

```
env['MYARGS'] = env.Literal(args)
```

Okay why do we need env.Literal() a second time? Because scons is "processing" again. Without it, the "$DOLLARP" inside args will immediately be translated into $p, which means once we "process" a 3rd time, scons will try to interpret $p. If this sounds confusing, this will be more clear once we look at the third scons invoke:

```
env.Execute('iscc $MYARGS')
```

As I said before, env.Execute(env.Literal(...)) does NOT work, so we pass $MYARGS instead. scons DOES substitute our created $MYARGS string for that, then apparently it does a SECOND substitution pass by finding $DOLLARP in that and substituting $p. Thankfully, scons does NOT do a third pass, and therein lies jackhab's trick.

I have NO idea why scons didn't just implement $$ which is what every other software package seems to do and would be a ton easier. But even if you don't understand the explanation, just try it, and it should work like magic for you.