# Inno Setup SignTool password request

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing, pfx, signtool

I am attempting to automate our code signing process in Inno Setup. Unfortunately we have a fairly strict protocol on the .pfx and password distribution, and only one person on the project can have access to it.

This would not be a problem in itself if all of the installs were compiled on that persons machine. SignTool could be set up in the IDE and, the password would remain secure on the users PC. However, we use a shared machine to compile our builds, so we cannot set the SignTool up as we cant leave that password so readily accessible. There are various reasons for this and cannot be altered.

What I would like to do is have Inno pop up an "Enter .pfx Password" dialogue after the compile is complete.

At current, my thinking is either to get Inno setup to request authentication, which I do not know how to do, or to write a small script which compiles the setup, and signs it outside of Inno setup. The later I could do relatively easily, but due to the nature of our workflow, it would be better all round if Inno setup could be harnessed for this.

Can anybody help me in getting Inno Setup to request a SignTool password for the .pfx file?

Comment: Which sign tool are you using ? Microsoft Sign Tool ? If so, you can use `signwizard` command, that will launch signing wizard which will prompt for password if needed. But consider what would all of you do when you compile the script by yourself. Would you call the boss for entering the password ? I would be for the latter idea you've mentioned and let the members of your team compile the unsigned installer and once you'll be done, let the boss sign it (from outside the InnoSetup).

Comment: Yes, using microsoft sign tool from the Windows sdk 7.1. The suggested solution doesn't work for us unfortunately, we compile in excess of 20-40 installers a day, spanning about 20 .iss files, so we cant pass on files for signing. This is why we want to tie it in to the build process in Inno, so that we can just skip signing if the key holder is not present, but for the majority of builds, he will be.

Part of the problem is that our testing is outsourced, and we rapidly go through builds, so after a compile is completed, it is live within minutes.

I will try using signwizard in Innosetup

Comment: Signtool /a will search for the cert, and you can install a private key without the ability to export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the key holder is ok with the builds being signed automatically rather than with his actual permission, then you could set up some kind of server program on his machine that does the signing, and change the command in Inno to hand the build off to that program over your network rather than calling signtool directly.  That way only his machine will know the password and/or possess the private key.

Alternatively, just forego signing builds until they have passed QA and are actually being released to customers.  Remove the [`SignTool`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_signtool.htm) setting and replace it with the [`SignedUninstaller`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setup_signeduninstaller.htm) setting.

When `SignedUninstaller` is used without `SignTool`, it will require the keyholder to manually sign the uninstall file once, and then this can be reused from a shared location without further resigning (until you upgrade Inno, at which point you need to do it again).  The script being built will have a signed uninstall but an unsigned output installer.  You can then pass it to QA and sign it manually later on when the keyholder is available (or discard it if it fails QA).

Comment: This was very helpfull information. I have half used this. What I have implemented is a python file, which reads the .pfx location from a local file which is not on SVN. Iff that file exists, python requests a password, and runs the sign tool.

I now need to figure out how to get inno setup to continue compiling if the sign fails

Comment: If you did what I suggested then it would only stop compilation if you hadn't used that particular version of Inno before.  The approach you're taking above will not work, as Inno ensures that the uninstaller has been correctly signed before proceeding.

Comment: IT security dictated that the Password can not be stored anywhere in any way other than mentally

Comment: That's not a problem if you followed my second suggestion.

Comment: Since version 6.0.4 it's no longer possible to sign the uninstaller once because a new one will be generated for every build version.

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY came up with a good and simple way to ask for the password based on ideas from a couple of websites (I'll post links at the bottom). Basically I ask for a password in a batch file (I didn't even know you could do that until today LOL). Then that password is dumped into an InnoSetup definition on the command line which is then used as part of the signing definition. The password is displayed on the screen when you type it in, and also when InnoSetup echos the SignTool command line, but after it scrolls off it disappears. Most importantly, it is NOT retained in the *.iss or any temporary file and thus must be typed each time.

Here's my batch file:

```
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Please enter password for certificate signing: %=%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\ISCC.exe" "/sStandard=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe sign /a /f C:\ConfidentialKeys\MyCompanysKey.p12 /p %INPUT% /tr http://timestamp.sectigo.com/?td=sha256 /td sha256 $p" Install.iss
```

And here's the relevant lines from Install.iss:

```
[Setup]
SignToolRetryCount=2
SignToolRetryDelay=3000
SignToolMinimumTimeBetween=3000
SignTool=Standard /d $qMy Program Name$q $f
SignedUninstaller=yes
```

So yeah it's a bit cryptic to set up (InnoSetup documentation is rather poor on this) but now that I have this recipe it is really slick!

Relevant helpful references:

https://doughennig.blogspot.com/2009/11/executable-signing-with-inno-setup.html

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/c8cb6faa-749b-4b26-bc2a-ed4a324d18b8/how-to-make-signtool-pop-up-a-dialog-prompting-for-password?forum=windowscompatibility